# Typesafe repo: where have most of the packages been moved?

Tags: sbt, typesafe

Typesafe's repository no longer contains all the packages it contained a few days ago... I read they are migrating to a new CDN and that user shouldn't have impact... but most of the package are no longer there. Where have they actually been moved?

**EDIT**
As requested by jsuereth, here below are the packages I'm looking for:

```
"joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.6"
"org.joda" % "joda-convert" % "1.7"
"com.wordnik" %% "swagger-play2" % "1.3.12"
"com.wordnik" %% "swagger-play2-utils" % "1.3.12"
"com.google.guava" % "guava" % "18.0"
"com.google.zxing" % "core" % "3.2.0"
"com.google.zxing" % "javase" % "3.2.0"
"org.apache.mahout" % "mahout-core" % "0.9"
"org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-core" % "1.2.1"
"org.bitcoinj" % "bitcoinj-core" % "0.12"
"com.nimbusds" % "nimbus-jose-jwt" % "3.4"
"com.typesafe.play.plugins" %% "play-plugins-mailer" % "2.3.1"
"commons-codec" % "commons-codec" % "1.9"
"com.google.zxing" % "core" % "3.2.0"
"com.google.zxing" % "javase" % "3.2.0"
```

... anyway if you look at the [repo](http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/) most of the package available a few days ago are no longer there.

Comment: Can you list which packages are missing?  We'll fix ASAP.

Comment: Just updated my post :-)

Comment: which URL were you using?

Also note on joda-time, and all of the things on maven-central, we no longer host those as those should be grabbed from maven-central.

Comment: I'm using this URL: repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typesafe did migrate to a new CDN lately ([Typesafe blog post](https://www.typesafe.com/blog/migrating-repos-to-bintray)).  With this move, all of the content that used to also be served from maven central via the http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases repository is gone.  Let's just say that this was a bad idea for everyone (We had frequent reports of timeouts and issues resolving).

All of this content is already served to the community through far better infrastructure.   Bintray has a mirror of maven central, (which is what we use for our repository) that you can use, called http://jcenter.bintray.com.   Additionally, maven central should have most of the artifacts you list.

If you find anything you need which is not in maven central, or the typesafe repository, please let us know and we'll fix it.